# keep radio button checked but change exported value

Tags: javascript, forms, pdf

let's say I have:
RB1 :  |A| |B| |C| with exported values according to choice (4, 4, 5)

respondent ticked first choice and exported value is 4 or 
respondent ticked second choice and exported value is 4 or
respondent ticked third choice and exported value is 5

I would like to keep respondent choice and have RB1 exporting values (1,2,3)

if respondent had ticked first choice and exported value is 1 or 
respondent had ticked second choice and exported value is 2 or
respondent had ticked third choice and exported value is 3

I already manually mapped all RBs' old and new exported values, how would you write the script please ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please share some code examples.

Comment: I did: 

var fRB1 = getField("RB1");
fRB1.exportValues = [1, 2, 3] ;

I can see on the form (Acrobat DC) that export values have changed but I lost the respondent choice (no button is ticked anymore) so when I want to export data, nothing is exported.

Answer (score 0):

I did:

var fRB1 = getField("RB1");
fRB1.exportValues = [1, 2, 3] ;

I can see on the form (Acrobat DC) that export values have changed but I lost the respondent choice (no button is ticked anymore) so when I want to export data, nothing is exported.